# Assertion in Java JUnit Testing

Tags: java, junit, assert

I am new to java and I am learning about JUnit testing, All examples I find online are about adding two number.

This is my method on class `SumOfAllSeries`

```
 static int getIndex(int[] array) {

    int max = 0;

    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if(array[i] > array[max]) {

            max = i;
        }   
    }

    return max;
}
```

This is what I tried to do on my JUnit and I cant seem to find it right, Please how can I test this code.I have an error: `The method assertArrayEquals(int[], int[]) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)` when I use `AssertEquals` it prints garbage and says expected is 4.

```
class SumOfAllSeriesTest {
    @Test
    void testGetIndex() {

        int array[] = {2,4,5,6,7};
        int calculateIndex = SumOfAllSeries.getIndex(array);

        assertEquals(4, calculateIndex);


    }

}
```

Update: I have tried to change array to 4 and used

```
assertEquals
```

Is this the correct way? I don't have anyone to ask and i want to understand this concept.

Comment: Post a [mcve]...

Comment: @Reimeus I have edited it please help me understand Junit

Comment: This has nothing to do with JUnit. The compiler error is pretty clear: the method expects two `int[]` as parameters, you give it an `int[]` and an `int`. What should it even mean for an `int[]` to be equal to an `int`?

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, i have updated the question, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: try to change the name of the variable `result` to `calculatedIndex`. Does that make more sense when reading?

Comment: thanks @TimothyTruckle cant believe i finally got this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that `getIndex()` method doesn't compute a sum.
It returns the index of the max value of the array.

Whatever, to assert the index of the max value or the sum,  you don't need to use `assertArrayEquals()` in your test.
You don't want to assert arrays content but the index or the sum.
So do instead :

```
Assert.assertEquals(24, results); // for sum
```

or

```
Assert.assertEquals(4, results); // for index
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so with JUnit it is simply me writing what is expected of the code on my Assertions?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure. What the framework could do with the array  to assert an `int ` equality ? Providing in the assert invocation the expected and the actual is really all you need.

Comment: Thanks dude, It clicked now. Appreciated.